# Basis of holomorphic 1-forms on smooth projective curve with affine equation $C\colon s^6 = t^{p+1}+1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $k = \mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ be a finite field with $p \equiv -1 \mod 6 $. Via Riemann-Hurwitz one can calculate that the genus of this curve equals $5(p-1)/2$ and hence the the space of holomorphic differentials $H^0(C,\Omega^1_{C/k})$ has dimension $5(p-1)/2$. Are there methods that can compute a specific basis of this vector space? I know that there are general forms of bases when we are working with smooth algebraic plane curves, but $C$ is not of that form. Any help or a point towards a reference would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you try section 2 of Moonen here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1006.3400.pdf
The result you want will be at the end of the section.

Comment: Also yours IS a plane curve so I'm not sure why you're claiming otherwise.

Comment: @arkady Right, I was confused. I'll have a look at the paper you send!